# 2 delete function in one controller yii2

Tags: yii2

I need to create 2 delete function(Album & Photos). Somehow it only have one delete  function in controller. How can i create 2 delete function in controller? I am still beginner to OOP and Yii2.

These are the example of what i am trying to explain.

**GalleryController.php**

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}

public function actionDeletePhoto($id)
{
    $this->findModelPhoto($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

Comment: and what is your question? Two delete action or Two model in one action?

Comment: two delete action in one controller.

Comment: Why not? You can use how many action do you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();
    $this->findModelPhoto($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

or there is another way, sometimes deleting could create an issue, so make one more addition column in database called "status" and set it 1 which means active and 0 is passive, and you can make actuion column by easily changing their status like the way below:

```
    public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $model = Model::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();

    $model->status=0;
    $model->save(false);
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger', "smth is deleted!");
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

in a view:

```
<?= Html::a('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>',
    ['/controller/delete-photo'],
    [
        'class' => 'photo-dlt',
        'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Delete photo'),
        'data' => [
            'method' => 'post',
            'confirm' => Yii::t('app', 'Do you want to delete this photo?'),
            'params' => ['id' => $photo->id],
        ],
    ]
); ?>
```

in a controller:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                    'delete-photo' => ['POST'] // add this line of code
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

public function actionDeletePhoto()
    {
        $path = "path/to/photo";

        $id = Yii::$app->request->post('id');
        $model = $this->findModelPhoto($id);
        unlink($model->image, $path);
        $model->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);        
    }
```